# java print unicode characters to bash shell (mac OsX)

Tags: java, bash, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have this code in java 1.6:

```
System.out.println("\u00b2");
```

but on bash on OSX10.6 I get question marks and not the unicode characters...

actually I want to print the characters 176,177,178 on the extended ascii code (look here http://www.asciitable.com/) to create some art on the bash terminal..

any idea?

thanks

Comment: actually these unicode characters would be fine.. U+2591 ░ Light shade
U+2592 ▒ Medium shade
U+2593 ▓ Dark shade , but "\u2592" doesn't seem to work either..

Comment: This depends on your terminal settings (and what Java thinks about these terminal settings), not really the shell.

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as **extended ASCII**. This page probably means [Codepage 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works for me in UTF-8 enabled Terminal.app on Mac OS X 10.6.7:

```
# code taken from: 
# "Print Unicode characters to the Terminal with Java",
# http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050208053951714

echo '
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
class Test {
  public static void main (String[] argv) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  String unicodeMessage = "\u00b2\u2591\u2592\u2593";
  PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
  out.println(unicodeMessage);
  }
}
' > test.java

javac test.java
java Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Is bash in a UTF8 locale?  Type in the *locale* command and see if your LANG looks appropriate (e.g. something like *en_GB.UTF-8*).  If not, update the value of LANG and try again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to be certain that the character encoding in your terminal session matches what your java application is outputting.  You most likely want UTF-8 which I believe is standard under OS X.

Next you need to be certain that the font used in your terminal session actually contains the characters you want to see.  These seem to be rare and may not be available in all fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that `Terminal > Preferences > Encodings`  has UTF-8 checked.