# Print all Unicode characters within a specific range

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode

I can't find the right API for this. I tried this;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 2309; i < 3000; i++) {
      String hex = Integer.toHexString(i);
      System.out.println(hex + " = " + (char) i);
    }
  }
```

This code only prints like this in Eclipse IDE.

```
905 = ?
906 = ?
907 = ?
...
```

How can I make us of these decimal and hex values to get the Unicode characters?

Comment: Silly mistake! I did not save it in UTF-8 format. Now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

It prints like that because all consoles use a mono spaced font. Try that on a JLabel in a frame and it should display fine.

***EDIT:***

Try creating a unicode printstream

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
```

And then print to it.

Here's the output in CMD window.

[image]

Comment: File > Properties > Select the text file encoding.

Comment: Also you need to set the printstream to make it work on a mac. From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384321/java-print-unicode-characters-to-bash-shell-mac-osx

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to save it in UTF-8 format by changing it from

> File > Properties > Select the text file encoding

This will properly print the right character from the Eclipse console. The default is cp1252 which will print only `?` for those characters it does not understand.

Comment: How to do that in netbeans please ?