# weired character handling in java

Tags: java

I am retrieving data from DB table.
IN DB table I have weired character values e.g. ñ
(Although there are many ,I am able to copy only this here in this post.  Other e.g A and upon it char like ^ etc)

when I try to retrieve from DB and put in my hashMap its showing strange behavior.
1)actual count of map is different from DB table count (less count) (may be skipping some character row but not sure why)

2)when I printed hashMap , I am seeing instead ñ it has added ? there.

```
Map m = new HashMap();
rs= statement.execteQuery("select A,B from table Test");
while(rs.next()){
 map.put(rs.getString("A"),rs.getString("B"));
}

Iterator itr = map.entrySet().iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry) itr.nxt();
System.out.println(m.getKey() + m.getValue()); // Here different values placed in Map instead actual values
}
```

How to handle these strange behavior and characters here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are A,B of type varchar(UTF-8) in database table? Check database encoding is UTF-8 or not.

Comment: See here to print unicode to verify its not just an issue with Java not printing unicode properly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16141477/2592585  Or ensure your code is compiling to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it. But I think along with DB do I need to do anything in java side ?

Comment: If you are using to an IDE, save your java classes with `UTF-8` encoding instead of the default `Cp1252`

Comment: It may not be skipping. HashMap may be overriding repeating keys. Instead of using HashMap try using a list.

Comment: I will try with list. But what if I want to use HashMap. Do I need to override hashcode() equals() method while putitng value in Map?